# Multi delimiter in split function

Tags: vb.net

I would like to split a string with the `Split` function in VB.NET, but I really need to split this string with many separator: "+", "-" ,"*", "%" and "/".

Here is my code :

```
' the print variable is the input string

Dim calcule As String = print
                ''
Dim Tableau() As String, i As Long
Tableau = Split(calcule, "+")
For i = LBound(Tableau) To UBound(Tableau)
    If var_i.Contains(Tableau(i)) Then
        Dim adrs As Integer = Array.FindIndex(var_i, Function(s) s = Tableau(i))
        calcule = calcule.Replace(var_i(adrs), var(adrs))
    End If
Next
''
Dim result = New DataTable().Compute(calcule, Nothing)
```

This is the fourth line I would like to change. Haven't you got a solution for me?

Comment: The [String.Split Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) takes multiple delimiters

Comment: Sorry if an other post have been create, I haven't see it :/